# How can I refine this MySQL query to return only selected columns and choose their order?

Tags: mysql

Could someone help me refine this query please?

```
SELECT * FROM `tblOrderItems` 
LEFT JOIN `tblOrder` USING(`order_id`)
WHERE `order_status` != 0
AND  `order_id` > 1234
ORDER BY `order_id` ASC
```

I'd like to be able to select what columns of data are returned and in which order to display them.

Example column names are `product_id`, `order_date`, `product_qty`

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

basic SQL:

```
SELECT product_id, order_date, product_qty
FROM `tblOrderItems` 
LEFT JOIN `tblOrder` USING(`order_id`)
WHERE `order_status` != 0
AND  `order_id` > 1234
ORDER BY `order_id` ASC
```

Select sentence is for selecting columns & its order.